# Prove n is a product of a square and a cube

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $n\ge 2$ is an integer with the property that whenever a prime
>   $p$ divides $n$, $p^2$ also divides $n$ (i.e., all primes in the prime factorization of $n$ appear at least to the power $2$). Prove that $n$ can be written as the product of a square and a cube.

Since $p | n \Rightarrow p^2 |n$, $n=p_1^{2b_1}\dotsc p_m^{2b_m}$, but why on earth does $n$ equal to a product of square and a cube?

Comment: Hint:  your implication is wrong.  For example, $2^2|2^3$.

Comment: Observe that, for example, $p^5$ satisfies this property, but is not a perfect square.

Comment: ^ the number needn't be a perfect square

Comment: lulu he's trying to find $n$ that satisfies the condition. We know that not all numbers would satisfy it

Comment: @OussamaBoussif ?  The OP argued that $p^2|n\Rightarrow n=p_1^{2b_1}...$.  I was giving a counterexample to that claim.

Comment: ah I tought you were contradicting the claim of the problem ^^

Comment: @lulu. No, he's saying every p^n where $n \ge 2$ can be expressed as $p^{2m} \cdot p^{3n}$, which is true if you allow $m, n \ge 0$.

Comment: @StevenGregory Perhaps I am misreading (always possible).  I am referring to where he claims  "Since $p|n \Rightarrow p^2|n, n=p_1^{2b_1}...p_m^{2b_m}$.  That implication is false.  the fact that $p^2|n$ whenever $p|n$ does not mean $n $ is a square (though he has written that it does).

Comment: @lulu : Yes, he showed his work and it was wrong. Sorry. I didn't even notice that.

Comment: @StevenGregory no worries.  My guess is that this is the point that threw him.  If you've already shown it's a square, where on earth would the cube come from?  Anyway, that was my guess.

Comment: Such numbers are also described in [OEIS A001694](https://oeis.org/A001694).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the canonical representation $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$. As given, we know that $e_i\ge 2$ for all $i$. Now comes the trick: if $e_i$ is even then it is a factor of a perfect square. If $e_i$ is odd, since it is greater than $2$, it is of the form $2m+3$ so we can factor out a $p_i^{e_i-3}$ which is thus even.

WLOG, lets assume that $e_1\cdots e_a$ are even and $e_{a+1}\cdots e_k$ are odd. Then we can rewrite $n$ as

$n=(p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_a^{e_a})(p_{a+1}^{e_{a+1}}\cdots p_k^{e_k})$

$n=(p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_a^{e_a}p_{a+1}^{e_{a+1}-3}p_{a+2}^{e_{a+2}-3}\cdots p_k^{e_k-3})(p_{a+1}^3p_{a+2}^3\cdots p_k^3)$

The left factor is a perfect square since every exponent is even; the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

First, as it has been said in comments, the exponents needn't be even.

But odd exponents are $\ge 3$, so if $q_1,\ldots,q_r$ are the prime factors of $n$ with odd exponents, $h=q_1^3\cdot\ldots\cdot q_r^3$ is a perfect cube that divides $n$ and $n/h$ is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ be the canonical representation of $n$ (since $n\ge 2$, then $k\ge 1$). The standing assumption is equivalent to say that
$$
\min\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\ge 2.
$$
For each $i=1,\ldots,k$ define $b_i=a_i/2$ if $a_i$ is even, and $b_i=(a_i-3)/2$ if $a_i$ is odd. It follows that 
$$
m:=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}
$$
is an integer such that $m^2 \mid n$ and $\frac{n}{m^2}$ is a cube.